# React production build results with blank page. Dev server works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I'm developing react app. Ejected from create-react-app.

`npm start` works fine. No console errors.

`npm run build` builds app with success. But when I try to open index.html there is blank page. No errors. Every file in network tab downloaded with success.

I have no idea how to debug? Tried lots of solutions but none worked.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "debug": true,
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.0.1",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.*",
    "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.*",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-hash-link": "1.2.*",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.*",
    "react-scrollchor": "4.2.*",
    "recharts": "0.22.*",
    "redux": "3.7.*",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.*",
    "scrollreveal": "3.3.6",
    "seamless-immutable": "7.1.*",
    "semantic-ui": "2.3.*",
    "semantic-ui-css": "2.3.*",
    "semantic-ui-react": "0.78.*",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "0.11.*",
    "react-async-script": "0.9.*",
    "raven-js": "3.25.*",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.*",
    "each-async": "*",
    "indent-string": "*",
    "validator": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "2.23.6",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "3.9.2",
    "gulp-header": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "rebuild-node-sass": "*",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "console-log-shortcut": "1.0.*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "mjs",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

build.js

```
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');

const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../config/webpack.config.prod');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const formatWebpackMessages = require('react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages');
const printHostingInstructions = require('react-dev-utils/printHostingInstructions');
const FileSizeReporter = require('react-dev-utils/FileSizeReporter');
const printBuildError = require('react-dev-utils/printBuildError');

const measureFileSizesBeforeBuild =
  FileSizeReporter.measureFileSizesBeforeBuild;
const printFileSizesAfterBuild = FileSizeReporter.printFileSizesAfterBuild;
const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);

// These sizes are pretty large. We'll warn for bundles exceeding them.
const WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE = 512 * 1024;
const WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// First, read the current file sizes in build directory.
// This lets us display how much they changed later.
measureFileSizesBeforeBuild(paths.appBuild)
  .then(previousFileSizes => {
    // Remove all content but keep the directory so that
    // if you're in it, you don't end up in Trash
    fs.emptyDirSync(paths.appBuild);
    // Merge with the public folder
    copyPublicFolder();
    // Start the webpack build
    return build(previousFileSizes);
  })
  .then(
    ({ stats, previousFileSizes, warnings }) => {
      if (warnings.length) {
        console.log(chalk.yellow('Compiled with warnings.\n'));
        console.log(warnings.join('\n\n'));
        console.log(
          '\nSearch for the ' +
            chalk.underline(chalk.yellow('keywords')) +
            ' to learn more about each warning.'
        );
        console.log(
          'To ignore, add ' +
            chalk.cyan('// eslint-disable-next-line') +
            ' to the line before.\n'
        );
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.green('Compiled successfully.\n'));
      }

      console.log('File sizes after gzip:\n');
      printFileSizesAfterBuild(
        stats,
        previousFileSizes,
        paths.appBuild,
        WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE,
        WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE
      );
      console.log();

      const appPackage = require(paths.appPackageJson);
      const publicUrl = paths.publicUrl;
      const publicPath = config.output.publicPath;
      const buildFolder = path.relative(process.cwd(), paths.appBuild);
      printHostingInstructions(
        appPackage,
        publicUrl,
        publicPath,
        buildFolder,
        useYarn
      );
    },
    err => {
      console.log(chalk.red('Failed to compile.\n'));
      printBuildError(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  );

// Create the production build and print the deployment instructions.
function build(previousFileSizes) {
  console.log('Creating an optimized production build...');

  let compiler = webpack(config);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    compiler.run((err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      const messages = formatWebpackMessages(stats.toJson({}, true));
      if (messages.errors.length) {
        // Only keep the first error. Others are often indicative
        // of the same problem, but confuse the reader with noise.
        if (messages.errors.length > 1) {
          messages.errors.length = 1;
        }
        return reject(new Error(messages.errors.join('\n\n')));
      }
      if (
        process.env.CI &&
        (typeof process.env.CI !== 'string' ||
          process.env.CI.toLowerCase() !== 'false') &&
        messages.warnings.length
      ) {
        console.log(
          chalk.yellow(
            '\nTreating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.\n' +
              'Most CI servers set it automatically.\n'
          )
        );
        return reject(new Error(messages.warnings.join('\n\n')));
      }
      return resolve({
        stats,
        previousFileSizes,
        warnings: messages.warnings,
      });
    });
  });
}

function copyPublicFolder() {
  fs.copySync(paths.appPublic, paths.appBuild, {
    dereference: true,
    filter: file => file !== paths.appHtml,
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the `build` directory and using something like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) in your command line and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, and it gave me strange error:

    `⇒  serve -s`
    `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js:32`
    `const updateCheck = async (isDebugging) => {`
                              ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)